# Is it possible to integrate Gmail threads to Trello?

Tags: gmail, trello, integration

I use Trello for project managing and I really want to share email threads to my Trello comments in cards.

It is something like this: "team" <--(Trello)--> "I" <--(email)--> "partners". I always copy and paste mail threads from my business partners to Trello and it is uncomfortable.

Answer (score 1):

There are two "webapps" that can combine Trello with Gmail: [Gmello](http://www.gmelloapp.com/) and [Emello](http://www.emelloapp.com/). You might find them interesting.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually quite a few users on Zapier who use [this zap](http://zpr.io/22X) to create cards with the contents of an email based on the what label the email has. You should be able to create new comments on a trello card from an email as well.

Disclaimer: I work at Zapier but even if I didn't this is how I'd do it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tried Gmello too, but ended up using [Gmail to Trello Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-to-trello/oceoildfbiaeclndnjknjpfaoofeekgl?hl=ru), working good and easy to use.